# Cada 4 segundo crear un cuadrado en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy haciendo un juego en pygame y quiero hacer que cada 4 segundo aparezca un cuadrado y se mueva a la derecha. He hecho un timer que cada 4 segundo añada a una lista la coordenada del eje x inicial y después con un bucle for recorro la lista utilizando cada indice como posición de un cuadrado. El problema está en el timer que he creado:

```
start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
while run:
    seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_ticks) / 1000
    if (seconds % 4) == 0:
        green_dinos_x.append(50)
        print(seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu enfoque tiene problemas. Fijate en este caso, en que ejecutas una iteración con milisegundos = 3999 y milisegundos = 4001 (tres milisegundos de diferencia):

```
start_ticks = 0

seconds = (3999 - start_ticks) / 1000
print(seconds % 4) => 3.999
seconds = (4001 - start_ticks) / 1000
print(seconds % 4) => 0.001000000000000334
```

Como se aprecia, `seconds` es un `float` por lo que `seconds % 4` da cero sólo cuando han transcurrido exactamente 4000 ms entre dos iteraciones.

Una solución es usar `int()`

```
start_ticks = 0

seconds = int((3999 - start_ticks) / 1000)
print(seconds % 4) => 3
seconds = int((4001 - start_ticks) / 1000)
print(seconds % 4) => 0
```

pero no es perfecto. ¿Qué pasa si el tiempo entre dos iteraciones resultan ser 6 segundos? No es múltiplo de cuatro y se perdio una ejecución.

La solución es calcular el tiempo pasado y proceder solo cuando supera los 4 segundos:

```
start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
while True:
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if now - start_ticks >= 4000:
        green_dinos_x.append(50)
        start_ticks = now
```